# Is $f$: $(\mathbb{R}^m$, $\vert \vert \circ \vert \vert)$ $\rightarrow$ $(\mathbb{R}$, $\vert \circ \vert)$ a linear map?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Given that $f$ is continuous between two normed spaces, is it a linear map?

Because I think it is a map between two normed linear spaces, I think that it is but I'm not sure if that is true.

Also, if this is the case, would it be correct to say that $f$ is bounded because  it is continuous?

Comment: No, most continuous functions are not linear. For example $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous and not linear. For linear maps, bounded (in the sense of functional analysis) and continuous is the same thing. Between finite dimensional normed space all linear maps are bounded.

Answer (score 2):

For a normed space $(V, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$, there is an immediate non linear map... The map $N: x \mapsto \Vert x \Vert$ itself as for $x \neq 0$

$$\Vert - x \Vert = \vert -1 \vert \Vert x \Vert = \Vert x \Vert \neq - \Vert x \Vert.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is correct to say that a linear map between normed spaces is bounded when continuous. In fact, in this situation being bounded and continuous are **equivalent** for linear maps.

This gives a way to disprove your first claim: find a continuous but unbounded function between normed spaces. Then, by what we have just observed, it will necessarily **fail** to be linear.